# How to add qml map to qgraphicscene widget?

Tags: c++, qt, maps, development-environment, thunderforest

I want to add a qml map to qgraphicscene instead of qquickwidget, can anyone please help me do it fast?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow window;
    QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(&window);
    QGraphicsView* graphicsView = new QGraphicsView(scene);
    window.setCentralWidget(graphicsView);
    
    QQuickWidget* qmlWidget = new QQuickWidget;
    qmlWidget->setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/map.qml")));
    qmlWidget->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);

    QGraphicsProxyWidget* proxyWidget = scene->addWidget(qmlWidget);
    proxyWidget->setMinimumSize(qmlWidget->size());
    proxyWidget->setMaximumSize(qmlWidget->size());

    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

I tried this snippet of code, but it didn't worked.